# Adding Minimize and Close buttons in visual webparts in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am creating a visual webpart in SharePoint 2010 and I want to add Minimize and Close buttons in it.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the web part properties and in the "Advanced" section tick the "Allow Minimize" and "Allow close" checkboxes.